# Make smaller a swf in the browser is Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, size, flash

Is there a way to change the size of swf, (in the example the size is `750 X 750`) to `500 x 500` but only when the browser is IE6,IE7,IE8,IE9?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swffit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.allowfullscreen = true;
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "MYSWF";
        attributes.name = "MYSWF";
        swfobject.embedSWF("MYSWF.swf", "MYSWF","100%","100%","9.0.0",false,flashvars,params,attributes);
        swffit.fit("MYSWF", 750, 750);
    </script>
```

Comment: Why do you need a different size in a different browser?

Comment: Because, IE9 has some weird behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you mean only when the browser is IE. try this;

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.allowfullscreen = true;
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "MYSWF";
attributes.name = "MYSWF";
swfobject.embedSWF("MYSWF.swf", "cementera","100%","100%","9.0.0",false,flashvars,params,attributes);

if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    swffit.fit("cementera", 500, 500);
} else {
    swffit.fit("cementera", 750, 750);
}
```